# Why is "PMO Cares" in India not under Right to Information?

Tags: india, covid-19

Why is PM Cares fund not under the purview of right to information yet being managed by the prime minister's office (PMO). Does the prime minister of India have the option to not answer RTI?

During this time of crisis in India due to coronavirus where millions of USD's worth of funds are being collected everyday by the fund for disaster relief yet it is reported in news media that this fund is not under RTI. Could you please explain why this is so.

https://www.indiatoday.in/india/story/pm-cares-fund-not-transparent-shashi-tharoor-questions-govt-1661261-2020-03-30

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://rti.gov.in/rti-act.pdf) is the text of the RTI Act. It applies to entities:

> established, constituted, owned, controlled or substantially financed
>   by funds provided directly or indirectly—
>
> (i) by the Central Government or the Union territory administration, the Central
>   Government;
>
> (ii) by the State Government, the State Government;

In order to demand information about PMO Cares under the Act, it would need to be demonstrated that the organization fits this definition. The fact that Modi sits on the board does not in itself qualify.